# Execution time increases with increasing map jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, sqoop

I am trying to migrate some data from MySQL to HBase using sqoop import. Here is the command I'm using:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/database --username username -P
--query 'SELECT * FROM logs WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by log_id -m 4
--hbase-table logs --column-family cf --hbase-create-table
```

The issue is that the execution time increases when no of maps are increased. Since the parallel processing is done with the increase of mappers, so ideally the execution time should actually decrease.

Here is the pattern

```
No. of Maps     Time(in sec)
    1               16
    2               20
    4               29
    8               51
    10              55
    16              82
    25              122
```

From what can be seen from above, it takes least time when only one mapper is there. Any idea what could be the reason? Any help will be highly appreciated.
My cluster consists of a namenode and two datanodes.

Comment: How much data is there?

Comment: Its a test env, hence small dataset of about 25k records, the size being about 15MB.

Comment: That's essentially zero data, so you're almost certainly being swamped by overhead and DB thrashing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the load on mySQL when running multiple queries simultaneously. Also it seems from the total running time (16sec) that you are importing very small data so adding more maps increases overhead but each map only handles a small data segment so the overhead isn't offset. Lastly you didn't say much about your cluster (which I am guessing is a small test one), so if you are allocating more mappers than slots mappers will wait until there are free slots increasing the time even more

Comment: yeah I am testing with small dataset in my testing env, having about 25k records. And I have 2 datanodes each having HBase region server, so that would mean that the process with 2 maps should be faster than the single map, but this isn't the scenario.

Comment: two maps doesn't mean they were sent to two servers and a 4 sec diff for setting 2 map jobs is insignificant. esp since I am not sure if this is a map-only job (i.e. there may be synchronization in the reducer) .Note that insignificant here is in respect to what hadoop was designed for. The overhead of setting multiple map (and reduce) jobs is offset by the parallelism gained in *large* datasets that cannot fit into memory or a single server.

Comment: Makes sense. That insignificant delay may be bcoz of the overhead of splitting the job. Hoping this issue will fade away when working with large dataset.